# Can Scrum methodologies used for electrical engineering development?

Tags: scrum

I would like to know if Scrum methodologies can be used in electrical engineering development.

Comment: Where else can someone ask about Scrum except in a Programming environment.  Yes -- in one sense -- it's off topic.  But it seems that sharing some processes or techniques outside the narrow confines of programming can be of value.

Comment: Scrum is not methodologies, Its a framework to achieve Agility (Agile methodology). Scrum is good for any kind of project preferably complex project where requirements are not even clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrum is just an iterative process, so it can be pretty much applied to whatever you like.

Yes.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know if Scrum methodologies can be used in electrical engineering development

Yes you can.You can do whatever you want as long as it benefits your organisation.

Pardon me if I am being presumptuous but are you really meaning to ask the below question?

> I would like to know if Scrum methodologies would be beneficial in electrical engineering development?

Do you have the following?  1. a product or final product vision 2. a cross functional team who builds that product 3. product requirements which can be converted to bit sized shippable product user stories 4. and it is technically possible to work in as less as 2 weeks to 1 month iterations 5. a collocated team

If you have most of the above in your favor then it should work great for you, even if you don't, there is nothing that stops you from using Scrum in EE Development.

Comment: 1. yes 2. yes 3. No, in EE development you cannot deliver parts of the final product. 4. For some small task maybe. 5. yes
Just because of 3, I'm not sure that scrum will work great.

Comment: Interesting point. Hmmm I wonder if anyone is practicing Scrum for EE in this world.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use 'standard project management' methodologies in Electrical Engineering? If the answer is "yes", then you can use Scrum.  Scrum is "a team-based framework to develop complex systems and products”.  Scrum is *not* a 'silver bullet'; it will not magically resolve the issues the Team and Organization have.  What it *is* is a 'silver mirror' that will reveal dysfunctions, and provide a framework and processes to help resolve them.  The Scrum Alliance site has a wealth of information available; A good initialization might be http://agileanarchy.wordpress.com/2009/09/20/simple-scrum/

Many non-Software (and non-Engineering) groups are adopting Scrum.